# Getting result from other perl script through system call

Tags: perl

I know that I can use require and do this in a different fashion, but I'm just toying around with perl and ran into something that I don't know how to explain.

Here's my first script:

```
use 5.16.2;
use warnings;

sub get
{
print "hello";
}

get();
```

Test script:

```
use 5.16.2;
use warnings;

my $val=system('perl test.pl');
print "$val\n";

#prints: hello0, I surmised that 0 is the return code for system
```

I looked up how to ignore the 0 and got something that was wrong, but led me to this:

```
print '', system('perl test.pl');

#also prints hello0

my $val='', system('perl test.pl');
print "$val\n";
#prints: hello
```

This works, but I have absolutely no idea as to why.  I'm also confused as to why the one preceding it didn't work.  Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
print '', system('perl test.pl');
```

calls `print` with two arguments, namely `''` (the empty string: no effect) and `system('perl test.pl')` (which evaluates to `0`, as you saw, provided that `perl test.pl` runs successfully).

Using more parentheses to be more explicit, you can write the above as:

```
print('', system('perl test.pl'));
```

Or you can write it as:

```
my $val = system 'perl test.pl'; # prints 'hello', sets $val to zero
print '', $val; # prints zero
```

This:

```
my $val='', system('perl test.pl');
```

declares `$val` as a local variable and sets it to `''` (the empty string), and (unrelatedly) calls `system('perl test.pl')`. Using parentheses for explicitness:

```
(my $val = ''), system('perl test.pl');
```

Or:

```
my $val = '';
system('perl test.pl'); # prints 'hello', discards exit-status
```

Comment: Thank you.  That makes a lot of sense.